# caffe: Check failed: bottom[0]->num_axes() == first_spatial_axis + num_spatial_axes_ (3 vs. 4) bottom num_axes may not change

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I modify the FCN net and design a new net,in which I use two ImageData Layer as input param and hope the net produces a picture as output.
here is the [train_val.prototxt](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24540229/) and the [deploy.prototxt](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24540245/)

the original picture and the label are both gray scale pics and sizes are 224*224.
I've trained a caffemodel and use infer.py to use the caffemodel to do a segmentation,but meet the error:

```
 Check failed: bottom[0]->num_axes() == first_spatial_axis + num_spatial_axes_ (3 vs. 4) bottom num_axes may not change.
```

here is the infer.py file:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
caffe_root = '/home/zhaimo/' 
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, caffe_root + 'caffe-master/python')

import caffe
im = Image.open('/home/zhaimo/fcn-master/data/vessel/test/13.png')
in_ = np.array(im, dtype=np.float32)
#in_ = in_[:,:,::-1]
#in_ -= np.array((104.00698793,116.66876762,122.67891434))
#in_ = in_.transpose((2,0,1))


net = caffe.Net('/home/zhaimo/fcn-master/mo/deploy.prototxt', '/home/zhaimo/fcn-master/mo/snapshot/train/_iter_200000.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
net.blobs['data'].reshape(1, *in_.shape)
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = in_
net.forward()
out = net.blobs['score'].data[0].argmax(axis=0)

plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('/home/zhaimo/fcn-master/mo/result/13.png')
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: is it possible that your input image `im` has a 2D shape and not 3D (with singleton dim fo rthe "channel")?

Comment: I am sorry I can not understand you,could you please make it more clear?

Comment: your net expects a 4D input: `1x1xHxW` my suspicion is that you provide it with `1xHxW` input (i.e., you omit  the "channel" dimension altogether). Can you see there is a difference between `1xHxW` 3D array and `HxW` 2D array?

Comment: I provide a 8bit gray scale pics as input in test phase because I thought the gray scale pics take up 1 channel.so how to change the input to solve this problem,please?

Comment: if you change to `net.blobs['data'].reshape(1, 1, *in_.shape)`. does it do the trick?

Comment: yes but I meet another error: `out = net.blobs['score'].data[0].argmax(axis=0)
KeyError: 'score'`  how to solve this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your net is expecting a 4D input of shape `1x1xHxW`. That is a batch with a single image that has only one channel with height and width `HxW`. Therefore, the input has two singleton leading dimensions. 
What you provide your net with is a batch with a single 2D image, that is the `shape` of your `in_` is only `HxW` - you are missing a singleton dimension for the channel dimension.
To solve your problem you need to explicitly add the singleton dimension:

```
 net.blobs['data'].reshape(1, 1, *in_.shape)
```

---

As for the `KeyError` you got, your [net](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24540245/) does not have any blob named `'score'`, you have `'upscore1'` and `'prob'`:

```
 out = net.blobs['prob'].data[0].argmax(axis=0)
```